# show 2 sum without join

Tags: mysql, sql

i want to show the sum of jumlah_pinjaman of this table 
[image]
and the sum of jumlah_simpanan of this table[image]
group by the no_anggota of this table [image]
i tried this query :

> SELECT anggota_2,anggota_1,jumlah_pinjaman,jumlah_simpanan FROM 
>   (SELECT no_anggota as anggota_1,sum(jumlah_pinjaman) as jumlah_pinjaman from pinjaman group by no_anggota) as A,
>   (SELECT no_anggota as anggota_2,sum(jumlah_simpanan) as jumlah_simpanan from data_simpanan group by no_anggota) as B 
>   group by anggota_1

but it resulted this : [image]

the jumlah_simpanan coloumn is not the result i wanted 
please help :)

Comment: What result do you want? Share your sample data and expected output in proper text here. Images are very bad way to share information here. We can't copy data from images to test query.

Comment: Since it involves 3 tables, you need to join the tables.  But since you don't give any information about the table relationships, nothing much I can do.

Comment: Why do you not want to use a join?

Comment: Yes, use join if it possible, i thought it is not possible to use join in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below query:

```
select a.no_anggota,
(select sum(p.jumlah_pinjaman) from pinjaman p where p.no_anggota = a.no_anggota) as sum_jumlah_pinjaman,
(select sum(d.jumlah_simpanan) from data_simpanan d where d.no_anggota = a.no_anggota) as sum_jumlah_simpanan
from anggota a
group by a.no_anggota;
```

Comment: @MochamadRamdannyLukman: Request you please select my answer as correct answer to your question.